# seeking convergence with optimize.fmin on scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a function I want to minimize with `scipy.optimize.fmin`. Note that I force a `print` when my function is evaluated.

My problem is, when I start the minimization, the value printed decreases untill it reaches a certain point (the value 46700222.800). There it continues to decrease by very small bites, e.g., 46700222.797,46700222.765,46700222.745,46700222.699,46700222.688,46700222.678
So intuitively, I feel I have reached the minimum, since the length of each step are minus then 1. But the algorithm keeps running untill I get a "`Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded`" error.

My question is: how can I force my algorithm to accept the value of the parameter when the function evaluation reaches a value from where it does not really evolve anymore (let say, I don't gain more than 1 after an iteration). I read that the options `ftol` could be used but it has absolutely no effect on my code. In fact, I don't even know what value to put for `ftol`. I tried everything from 0.00001 to 10000 and there is still no convergence.

Comment: As seth stated, please post the code or we can't do anything apart from send more links to the docs.

Comment: I can rephrase my question as follows: does anyone know how ftol and xtol have to be used? And does anyone know how to force a convergence when a certain level of non-evolution is reached? That is totally independent of any bit of codes.

Comment: I am having exactly the SAME issue with Scipy. I got so frustrated that I translated everything into Matlab, whose code is so un-user-friendly compared to Python, but it also suffers from the same problem. Maybe the optimizer just ignores xtol and ftol in certain situations.

Comment: @Titanic, the optimizer does not ignore `xtol` and `ftol`, but requires both constraints on them to stop. See my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is actually no need to see your code to explain what is happening. I will answer point by point quoting you.

> My problem is, when I start the minimization, the value printed decreases
>   untill it reaches a certain point (the value 46700222.800). There it
>   continues to decrease by very small bites, e.g.,
>   46700222.797,46700222.765,46700222.745,46700222.699,46700222.688,46700222.678

Notice that the difference between the last 2 values is `-0.009999997913837433`, i.e. about `1e-2`. In the convention of minimization algorithm, what you call values is usually labelled `x`. The algorithm stops if these 2 conditions are respected AT THE SAME TIME at the `n`-th iteration:

- convergence on `x`: the absolute value of the difference between `x[n]` and the next iteration `x[n+1]` is smaller than `xtol`
- convergence on `f(x)`: the absolute value of the difference between `f[n]` and `f[n+1]` is smaller than `ftol`.

Moreover, the algorithm stops also if the maximum number of iterations is reached.

Now notice that `xtol` defaults to a value of `1e-4`, about `100` times smaller than the value `1e-2` that appears for your case. The algorithm then does not stop, because the first condition on `xtol` is not respected, until it reaches the maximum number of iterations.

> I read that the options ftol could be used but it has absolutely no
>   effect on my code. In fact, I don't even know what value to put for
>   ftol. I tried everything from 0.00001 to 10000 and there is still no
>   convergence.

This helped you respecting the second condition on `ftol`, but again the first condition was never reached.

To reach your aim, increase also `xtol`.

The following methods will also help you more in general when debugging the convergence of an optimization routine.

- inside the function you want to minimize, print the value of `x` and the value of `f(x)` before returning it. Then run the optimization routine. From these prints you can decide sensible values for `xtol` and `ftol`.
- consider nondimensionalizing the problem. There is a reason if `ftol` and `xtol` default both to `1e-4`. They expect you to formulate the problem so that `x` and `f(x)` are of order `O(1)` or `O(10)`, say numbers between `-100` and `+100`. If you carry out the nondimensionalization you handle a simpler problem, in the way that you often know what values to expect and what tolerances you are after.
- if you are interested just in a rough calculation and can't estimate typical values for `xtol` and `ftol`, and you know (or you hope) that your problem is well behaved, i.e. that it will converge, you can run `fmin` in a `try` block, pass to `fmin` only `maxiter=20` (say), and catch the error regarding the `Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I understand that BOTH conditions (xtol and ftol) have to be satisfied in order to stop the process. Note that this is absolutely not understandable from the doc. And thank you for the tips in the end, of course I knew I could catch the error, but I really wanted to understand once for all this xtol/ftol mystery. I have to say that I find it scientifically very strange that both conditions are needed.

Comment: I agree that the docs could be better written, but are not wrong: they talk about acceptable errors in convergence, for both x and ftol, suggesting that the convergence of both is required. As to why they are both enforced, the algorithm policy is as conservative as possible by default and will lead to fewer false positives, leaving up to you to relax the constraint on either of the conditions by setting a large `xtol` or `ftol`.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent three hours digging into the source code of [scipy.minimize](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/optimize/optimize.py). In it, the "while" loop in function "_minimize_neldermead" deals with the convergence rule:

```
if (numpy.max(numpy.ravel(numpy.abs(sim[1:] - sim[0]))) <= xtol and
               numpy.max(numpy.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= ftol):
    break"
```

"fsim" is the variable that stores results from functional evaluation. However, I found that fsim[0] = f(x0) which is the function evaluation of the initial value, and it never changes during the "while" loop. fsim[1:] updates itself all the time. The second condition of the while loop was never satisfied. It might be a bug. But my knowledge of mathematical optimization is far from enough to judge it.

My current solution: design your own system to control the convergence. Add this in your function:

```
global x_old, Q_old
if (np.absolute(x_old-x).sum() <= 1e-4) and (np.absolute(Q_old-Q).sum() <= 1e-4):
    return None
x_old = x; Q_old = Q
```

Here Q=f(x). Don't forget to give them an initial value.

**Update 01/30/15**: 
I got it! This should be the correct code for the second line of the if function (i.e. remove numpy.absolute):

```
numpy.max(fsim[0] - fsim[1:]) <= ftol)
```

btw, this is my first debugging of a open source software. I just created an [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4484) on GitHub.

**Update 01/31/15 - 1**: 
I don't think my previous update is correct. Nevertheless, this is the a screenshot of the iterations of a function using the original code. 
[image]

It prints the values of sim and fsim variable for each iteration. As you can see, the changes of each iteration is less than both of xtol and ftol values, but it just kept going without stopping. The original code compares the difference between fsim[0] and the rest of fsim values, i.e. the value here is always 87.63228689 - 87.61312213 = .01916476, which is greater than ftol=1e-2.

**Update 01/31/15 - 2**: 
Here is the [data and code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdzp4nrc8xvj3yw/fmin_Error.zip?dl=0) that I used to reproduce the previous results. It includes two data files and one iPython Notebook file.

Comment: Regarding the first part, please provide an example code where `fsim[0]` never changes with time. At the end of the loop you mention, `fsim` is actually updated, see [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L507) line. Regarding the update, I do not see how removing the `abs` makes sense in this context.

Comment: I'll look more into it later. But try that yourself and it works very well.

Comment: 1) How come you only have the code? The OP didn't post any code. 2) Why in the code of `blp()` you decrement the global variable `Delta`? You can't change a global variable inside of `blp()`. You can, if you really want to, read a global variable inside of `blp()`. That's why you have this weird behaviour of `fmin`.

Comment: OMG! @gg349, you made my day! I've spent so much time trying to find the cause of this. It's the problem with global variable. To answer your question, 1. OP didn't post any sample code, and I am experiencing the exact same problem as OP does, so I posted my own code for a well known Economics model.

Comment: 2. In that model, for each value of theta, one need to find the value of Delta that fits the model. To make it faster, the initial value of Delta given each theta is set to be the value of Delta given the previous theta. I decrement it just to make Delta_New and Delta to have different initial value so that the while loop starts to work. I'll definitely need to look more into how global variable works.

Comment: You can't do that then. You must make Delta part of x. Consider also using the args=() argument of fmin and ditch the use of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) it looks like you DO want to change the `ftol` arg.

Post your code so we can look at your progress.
edit: Try increasing `xtol` as well.

Comment: As I said in my post, I tried to change the arg ftol but It does not help. In fact, it has absolutely no effect on the convergence. I don't even know if it is a constant between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. Are you printing the value of your function, or the point where it is evaluated?

My understanding of `xtol` and `ftol` is as follows. The iteration stops

- when the change in the value of the function between iterations is less than `ftol`

AND

- when the change in `x` between successive iterations is less than `xtol`

When you say "...accept the value of the parameter...", this suggests you should change `xtol`.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity. I am printing the value of the function each time it is evaluated. And I want the algorithm to accepts the parameters whenever the values of the function change less than a certain value. So I should definitely use ftol. the fact is, this ftol does not work at all, since when I vary ftol from 0.000001 to 1000000, there is absolutely no diference in the process. Following your understanding, if I put ftol = 10000000, the algorithm should accept right away my parameters. But it is not the case.

Comment: @FuzzyDuck, this answer is wrong. Both conditions must be respected at the same time in order for the algorithm to stop.